# A topology over $C([0,1])$

Tags: general-topology

For each $f\in C([0,1])$, $x_1,..,x_n\in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon >0$, we consider $$U(f;x_1,...,x_n;\epsilon)=\{g\in C([0,1]):|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|<\epsilon, i\in\{1,...,n\}\}.$$

I want to show that these sets are a local base of $f$ for some topology over $C([0,1])$.

Now:

What I wish to show is that if $f\in U(g;y_1,...,y_m;\delta)$ then there exists a "nbhood" of $f$, namely $U(f;x_1,...,x_m;\epsilon)$ such that

$$U(f;x_1,...,x_m,\epsilon)\subseteq  U(g;y_1,...,y_m;\delta) .$$

All I know is that $|f(y_i)-g(y_i)|<\delta$ for every $i\in\{1,...,m\}$. What $x_1,...,x_n,\epsilon$ should I take? Any hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neighbourhood $U(g,\delta)$ of $g$ that you take "knows" only about the points $y_1,\ldots,y_m$. We can't control the behavior of $f$ outisde those points (it can take arbitrary values); therefore, we put $$\forall i\quad x_i=y_i.$$

After that it easy to see (use triangle inequality) that if we take $$\epsilon <\delta- \sup_i |g(x_i)-f(x_i)|,$$ then $U(f,\epsilon)\subset U(g,\delta)$.